How to change DataDog java agent trace api version to V0.5
I am testing that sending datadog java agent trace to my local terminal. But the
default trace version is v0.4, and now I want to change the api version to v0.5 or v0.3.
My local system is windows
I had read the official documentation, and I have tried to use the jvm arguments
-Ddd.trace.api.version=v0.5
or config the environment variable
DD_TRACE_API_VERSION v0.5
all of them are ineffective. It was still v0.4 api version.
